# Spring mvc bootstrap inputfields uninteractable

Tags: spring, forms, model-view-controller, input

Having issues with bootstrap inputfields in my spring mvc backend school project. Having issues with unclickable input forms in my jsp files in the view controller.
Im supposed to submit an Racer's first and surname, however I am not able to post the data with the submit button since the forms are unclickable.

here is my --add_racer.jsp-- file.

```
<%@taglib prefix="/form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<head>
    <title>Add Racer</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
        <form:form method="post" action="/save_racer" modelAttribute="racer">

                <h4 class="text-primary text-center">Welcome, enter the Racer's details.</h4>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="firstName">First name:</form:label>
                    <form:input type="text" class ="form-control" path="firstName" placeholder="John"/>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="lastName">Last name:</form:label>
                    <form:input type="text" class= "form-control" path="lastName" placeholder="Doe"/>
                </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>


    </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form:form>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the .css stylesheet I was using was making the inputsfield lie in the background. For now I have disabled it, will post an update if I solve the spreadsheet defaults causing the error:

stylesheet used:
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css